# How to add negative padding-top to html element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to set negative "padding-top" to .container element using jQuery.
Value for padding-top will be the sum of .header element and .navigation element.
I tried code below but it didn't work.

```
//This don't work
const $headerHeight = $('.header').height();
const $navHeight = $('.nav').height();
$('.container').css('padding-top', -($headerHeight + $navHeight) + 'px');
```

It works while it's not negative value.
It adds style="padding-top: xxxpx" to .container like below
div class="container" style="padding-top: xxxpx"

```
//This works
const $headerHeight = $('.header').height();
const $navHeight = $('.nav').height();
$('.container').css('padding-top', ($headerHeight + $navHeight) + 'px');
```

I'd like to know how to write in case of "negative value".

Answer (score 2):

Padding cannot be negative: [Unlike margin properties, values for padding values cannot be negative.](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#value-def-padding-width)

CSS Box Model Module Level 3 specs: [Negative values for padding properties are invalid](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-box-3/#propdef-padding-top).

Comment: I didn't know that. Thank you so much for your help.